# What does it mean to have a thread got interrupted?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Say, I am spawning multiple threads in java using executorService as follows:

```
public class AbcThreadPool {

    private final AbcThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public InventoryAvailabilityThreadPool(final AbcRunnableFactory factory,
                                           final Integer poolSize) {
        executor = new AbcThreadPoolExecutor(factory, poolSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; ++i) {
            executor.execute(factory.createRunnable());
        }
    }

    private static class AbcThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

        private final AbcRunnableFactory factory;

        public AbcThreadPoolExecutor(final AbcRunnableFactory factory,
                                                       final int poolSize) {
            super(poolSize, poolSize, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
            this.factory = factory;
            allowCoreThreadTimeOut(false);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        if (!isShutdown() && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            execute(factory.createRunnable());
        }
    }
}
```

In afterExecute, we are using the condition that !isShutdown() && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()

I wanted to know what does it literally mean to have a thread shutdown or got interrupted here. In which case, we don't execute the runnable. For process shutdown or interrupt, I think its equivalent to CTRL + C. But in thread, they are small running things inside the process. How can there be any Ctrl + C that I killed only one of thread.

Comment: A thread gets interrupted because, say, you've literally invoked the `interrupt()` method on the thread. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: `public InventoryAvailabilityThreadPool(...` this won't compile ... `@Override
    protected void afterExecute(...` what do you override in `AbcThreadPool extends Object`? I understand your question, but what is doing this code ?